# Could I modify my LCD display to prevent it from going to sleep?

Tags: display

I have an LCD display on my work bench that I use with various machines.
I would like prevent it from momentarily going to sleep when I reboot a computer.
It would allow me to see the POST for a longer period of time.
It takes several seconds to turn back on after it goes into sleep mode.

Is there a pin I could pull or short that would keep it on all the time regardless of the computer's status?

I basically want to disable the power saving features of the monitor itself.

Comment: I'd love to know how to do this as well. Power-on delay became such a problem when diagnosing BIOS-level issues for me that I ended up getting a motherboard with a BIOS that supported an enforced POST delay. That might be a possible workaround if no answers are forthcoming.

Comment: Just brainstorming, but the "sleep when no signal" function must be connected to something that detects signal or lack thereof.  If the method of override would be to force a false-positive of "signal detected", that could work but would include the possible hazard of what the monitor would do if you feed it a signal it is incapable of dealing with.  Of course, this is all academic, since I din't know how to override signal detection.

Comment: based on VESA power standards http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_Display_Power_Management_Signaling that have been in place for CRT monitors (and thus applied to other displays), power saving features such as Stand By and Suspend depend on whether power is being sent to Horizontal and Vertical Sync pins.  So, to trick it into always being on, you'd have to supply power at all times to those pins.  Maybe through a specific USB laptop dock, or a KVM assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I couldn't find much about anyone successfully doing this... but, I did find this!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_Display_Power_Management_Signaling

Looks as if you can trick the Hsync and Vsync to thinking there is always a signal http://pinouts.ru/Video/VGA15_pinout.shtml in theory, it would stay ON.

Now what that signal should be is above my head. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the POST, why don't your just pause the boot process with "Pause" key on keyboard..
Once windows starts, you can write scripts that moves mouse randomly after some time to prevent display from sleeping..
It is not wise to disable power saving features although even if you can in first place.

Answer (score -1):

The power saving in the monitor is triggered by the "power off screen".

I have never had any issues leaving my monitors in the office or in the house on? As long as my power Options were correct, the screen doesn't turn off.

Comment: Some monitors take an exceptionally long time to boot up before displaying an image, even if a signal is present. One of mine does this. It would take so long that I'd only start seeing an image after Windows started to load.

Comment: Thanks @sidran32 never knew this as i haven't experienced  it. Cheers